Как обработать ошибку RetryAfter в aiogram3
Как в новой версии aiogram мне отловить ошибку retryAfter и уже работать с ее значениями, из этой ошибки мне нужно вытащить время(ex. Retry After 509 и мне надо вытащить 509)

У исключения TelegramRetryAfter есть поле retry_after с временем в секундах.
Лично я пользуюсь данным решением в виде client session middleware, которая обрабатывает это исключение и повторяет запросы через указанное время.
